Existence of solutions in linear programming
If a linear programming problem "maximize $c^{\top} x$ with $Ax \leq b$, $x \geq 0$" is feasible (there is an $x$ satisfying the constraints) and bounded from above (there is a number $M$ with $c^{\top} x \leq  M$ for all feasible $x$), it has a solution.
Typical proofs involve classical results from convex analysis (e.g., Fourier-Motzkin elimination, Farkas' lemma, strong duality, solutions occurring at one of the finitely many basic feasible solutions/extreme points of the polyhedron, convergence of the simplex algorithm, ...).
Question: Is it possible to prove it instead using traditional real analysis tools, along the lines of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem? That is, by starting from a sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of feasible points whose function values $c^{\top} x_k$ approach the problem's supremum and extracting a clever convergent subsequence whose limit is the desired solution? The obvious impediment is that the feasible set, although closed, need not be bounded and therefore not compact.
This seems like a natural approach for people without much background in convex analysis, but I can't recall ever having seen a proof along those lines.
Edit: Under the extra assumption that the set of optima is bounded, a standard appeal to the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem works, as outlined in the answer of @Zim below. I am mainly interested in the general case where the set of optima need not be bounded.

In, Understanding and Using Linear Programming, (theorem 4.2.3) the author doesn't seem to present difficult words. I read this book up to that part and understand the proof, but it doesn't cover the convex analysis deeply. However, it doesn't use Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

That's indeed one of the classical convex analysis approaches: showing that a solution occurs at one of the finitely many basic feasible solutions. I perfectly agree that such proofs are not difficult, it's just that I was curious about a potential different approach.

I think this kind of result is very much tight to the linear programming problem. Existence of an upper bound does not imply existence of a maximum: see $x\mapsto -\exp(x)$ is concave or $(x,y) \mapsto (xy-1)^2 + x^2$ which is polynomial.

Yes. In convex analysis, this is often known as the Weierstraß theorem. Its proof uses a simple application of a minimizing (or maximizing) sequence, as you describe. Since the polyhedral constraint set is already closed, the additional assumption of boundedness yields compactness of the feasible set on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence, existence of a solution follows as a corollary. A modern statement is in, e.g., Theorem 1.29 of Bauschke & Combettes' book Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces, 2nd edition.
Edit: In the case when $f$ has a bounded level set with a nonempty intersection with the feasible set, one can just apply Theorem 11.10 from the same book above.

I think the question is about the case where we do not have boundedness of the feasible set.

The question states " is feasible and bounded from above", which I suppose could be ambiguous, but the Weierstrass theorem covers both interpretations. Interpretation 1: The feasible set is bounded, hence we can just apply the compactness argument. Interpretation 2: The objective function is bounded from above, in which case our constraint can be intersected with a lower level set of the objective function without losing any points in the Argmin. Boundedness of the function from above should yield boundedness of the lower level set, from which comapctness follows.

I clarified my question: I was indeed interested in unbounded feasible sets. I don’t see how the second interpretation works: if we maximize in two-dimensional space, say, the second coordinate over a feasible set equal to the horizontal axis, also the feasible set with the extra constraint remains unbounded. Do I misunderstand your second interpretation?

@Mark thanks for the clarification; I've edited my answer to reflect the specific result I was referring to. Basically, if you can show that "bounded objective function" implies "bounded level set", you are done. However, $\langle c^\top x\rangle \leq M$ might not be sufficient, you might need the $|\langle c^\top x \rangle | \leq M$ notion of boundedness (unless this follows from some other part of the problem)
